# c++:how to get balance (in banking system)

Tags: c++, system, banking

i'm doing this project Banking System
This system tracks customers’ accounts in a bank. Each account has a number, name, and balance. The system provides the following functionalities: create new account, withdraw, deposit, and close account.
The system has the following interface:
Choose:
1- Add new account
2- Withdraw
3- Deposit
4- Get Balance
5- Exit
*** When the user chooses 1***, the system generates a new ID, and then asks the user to enter a name for that account. The initial balance is set to zero.

*** When the user chooses 2***, the system asks the user to enter account ID and amount to be withdrawn. If this amount is greater than the balance, a message is displayed that this transaction failed because insufficient balance. If balance is enough, it decreases by amount to be withdrawn.

*** When the user chooses 3***. The system asks the user to enter account ID and amount to be deposited. System increases balance by this amount.

*** When the user chooses 4***, the system asks the user to enter account ID then prints account’s name and balance.

 Each time a task is completed the system gets back to the main menu above until the user chooses 5.

```
# include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
# include<iomanip>

class Bank
{
private:
    char name;
    int acno;
    float balance;
public:
    void newAccount();
    void withdraw();
    void deposit();
    void getbalance();
    void disp_det();
    };
//member functions of bank class
void Bank::newAccount()
{
cout<<"New Account";
cout<<"Enter the Name of the depositor : ";
cin>>name;
cout<<"Enter the Account Number : ";
cin>>acno;
cout<<"Enter the Amount to Deposit : ";
cin >>balance;
}
void Bank::deposit()
{
float more;
cout <<"Depositing";
cout<<"Enter the amount to deposit : ";
cin>>more;
balance+=more;
}
void Bank::withdraw()
{
float amt;
cout<<"Withdrwal";
cout<<"Enter the amount to withdraw : ";
cin>>amt;
balance-=amt;
}
void Bank::disp_det()
{
cout<<"Account Details";
cout<<"Name of the depositor : "<<name<<endl;
cout<<"Account Number        : "<<acno<<endl;
cout<<"Balance               : $"<<balance<<endl;
}
// main function , exectution starts here
void main(void)
{
Bank obj;
int choice  =1;
while (choice != 5 )
{
cout<<"Enter \n 1- to create new account \n 2- Withdraw\n 3- Deposit \n 4- get balance\n 5 Exit"<<endl;
cin>>choice;
switch(choice)
{
    case '1' :obj.newAccount();
        break;
    case '2' :obj.withdraw();
        break;
    case 3: obj.deposit();
        break;
    case 4: getbalance();
        break;
    case 5: 
        break;
    default: cout<<"Illegal Option"<<endl;
}
}

}
```

Comment: please format your question and specify what exactly you need.

Comment: at the end in switch statement when i want to get the balance it becomes an error ! case 4: getbalance();
        break;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Problem 1:***
You have made a typo in method which gets you the balance & the one which you are calling, rename `Bank::disp_det()` to `Bank::getbalance()`

```
void Bank::getbalance()
{
    cout<<"Account Details";
    cout<<"Name of the depositor : "<<name<<endl;
    cout<<"Account Number        : "<<acno<<endl;
    cout<<"Balance               : $"<<balance<<endl;
}
```

***Problem 2:***
You are not calling `Bank::getbalance` through an object of `Bank`, Since it is a member function you should call it as follows:

```
case 4: 
     obj.getbalance();
     break;
```

Comment: @roody: Good for you :) You should consider marking an answer as accepted, Ofcourse, the one which helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In case 4, you should call `obj.getbalance()`. And it's not written yet: it seems you have written a `disp_det()` instead that shows the balance. Try renaming.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't doing exactly what you want, as the case labels have different types:

```
switch(choice)
{
    case '1' :obj.newAccount();
        break;
    case '2' :obj.withdraw();
        break;
    case 3: obj.deposit();
        break;
    case 4: getbalance();
        break;
    case 5: 
        break;
    default: cout<<"Illegal Option"<<endl;
}
```

To select options `'1'` or `'2'`, the user will have to type 31 and 32 when choice is an `int`.